# Confusing code with ? operator

Tags: c#

I was reading through someones old code and I found this line:

```
 menuItem.Checked = (menuItem.Checked == false) ? true : false;
```

I dont understand what it does and how. any help?

Answer (score 9):

It's a complicated way to write:

```
menuItem.Checked = !menuItem.Checked;
```

Answer (score 4):

Your statement means:

```
if(menuItem.Checked == false)
    menuItem.Checked = true;
else 
    menuItem.Checked = false;
```

Your statement is actually doing a toggle effect on the `menuItem`. If it is `Checked` then the statement is setting it to `UnChecked` and vice versa

From MSDN [?: Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

> The conditional operator (?:) returns one of two values depending on
>   the value of a Boolean expression. Following is the syntax for the
>   conditional operator.m

```
condition ? first_expression : second_expression;
```

Comment: It can also be understood as toggling the checked state of the menu item. i.e. menuItem.Checked = !menuItem.Checked;

Comment: @wenqiang, yes, I believe OP is confused about ? operator

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Conditional Operator: **? :**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) 
This means:

```
if(menuItem.Checked == false)
{
   menuItem.Checked = true;
}
else
{ 
   menuItem.Checked = false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be replaced with following code:

```
menuItem.Checked = !menuItem.Checked;
```

Answer (score 3):

That's the equivalent of :

```
 menuItem.Checked = !menuItem.Checked;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the MSDN article on it. It has links to other useful operators: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It's called Ternary Operators and a simple Google search gives great information about how this works and possibilities.

Take a look: https://www.google.com/search?q=Ternary+Operators+c%23

As people already have pointed out, this is just a shorter and easier way to write simple if-statements.

Answer (score 0):

It is called a ternary operator. It is used like an if else statement but more condensed. 
Its called ternary because it takes three operands. 
It evaluates the first, and then choses the second if true, third if false.